# Recover a file that cant be opened

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was making a blender project using geometry nodes and after tried to scatter some grass around, it crashed. Now of course I hadnt saved before doing that and the backup autosave that blender made is from after the edit that caused the crash. Is there any way I can recover this or do i just have to redo it? EDIT: the crash was probably from too much density.

Comment: Hello and welcome. yes you have to redo it.

Comment: You don't say what OS you are using, but if it's Windows you could try typing '%temp%' (without the quotes) into the Windows search field. This should open the Windows Temp folder and you **might** find some earlier autosave files there to get you out of trouble.

Comment: @BlueJay987, you can try to open a new blend file and try appending the node from "crashed blender autosaved file". But if the issue is because of density of the mesh generated by Geometry node, then once you attach the node network to a mesh, it may crash again.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The Cache folder just has an asset-library-indices folder in it here. The autosave files are in the Temp folder here as I indicated above.

Comment: File -> Recover -> Auto Save

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested in the comments, your best bet is to make a new file and attempt to append your objects or node groups from the problematic autosave. That's File->Append:

[image]